# MySQL-test suite not included with windows mysql installer?

Tags: mysql, windows

I noticed in my MySQL folder there is no mysql-test. Why is that?

Is it possible to add it?

Comment: Moderators, please do not close this. I answered this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must one of the following situations:

- Using an old version of MySQL/Windows (Missing from MSI or Zip File)
- Using a current version of MySQL/Windows (Missing from MSI or Zip File)

I have MySQL 5.6.14 for Windows installed on my Desktop at Work

```
C:\>cd MySQL_5.6.14

C:\MySQL_5.6.14>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A06D-D0B3

 Directory of C:\MySQL_5.6.14

10/01/2013  02:38 PM    <DIR>          .
10/01/2013  02:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          bin
12/14/2013  07:35 PM    <DIR>          data
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          docs
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          include
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          lib
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          mysql-test
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          scripts
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          share
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          sql-bench
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          support-files
09/30/2013  04:02 PM            17,987 COPYING
10/08/2013  08:26 AM               237 my.ini
09/30/2013  04:02 PM             1,141 my-default.ini
09/30/2013  04:02 PM             2,496 README
               4 File(s)         21,861 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  1,871,352,606,720 bytes free

C:\MySQL_5.6.14>
```

I went into the folder `mysql-test`

```
C:\MySQL_5.6.14>cd mysql-test

C:\MySQL_5.6.14\mysql-test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A06D-D0B3

 Directory of C:\MySQL_5.6.14\mysql-test

09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          .
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          collections
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          extra
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          include
09/30/2013  03:58 PM    <DIR>          lib
09/30/2013  03:59 PM    <DIR>          r
09/30/2013  03:59 PM    <DIR>          std_data
09/30/2013  04:01 PM    <DIR>          suite
09/30/2013  04:02 PM    <DIR>          t
09/30/2013  03:58 PM            36,862 mysql-stress-test.pl
09/30/2013  03:58 PM           190,060 mysql-test-run.pl
09/30/2013  03:58 PM             1,447 purify.supp
09/30/2013  03:58 PM             2,860 README
09/30/2013  03:58 PM               655 README.gcov
09/30/2013  03:58 PM             4,600 README.stress
09/30/2013  03:58 PM            21,064 valgrind.supp
               7 File(s)        257,548 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  1,871,352,606,720 bytes free

C:\MySQL_5.6.14\mysql-test>
```

It's there for me. I installed this a couple of month ago using the no-install zip file.

## SUGGESTION

Download the latest no-install zipfile for MySQL 5.6.15 and look for the `mysql-test` folder

## UPDATE 2013-12-16 13:00 EST

I just downloaded the no-install zip file. I looked in it and it is in there. Please download it and extract. Of course, make sure you have Perl installed on the Windows machine.